Handle Collector failures when using Opentelemetry in Java
I am trying to set up Open Telemetry in Spring Boot 3.2 application. I am using Micrometer + otel bridge to implement it.
One issue i have noticed when testing the implementation is that if the collector is not available, the processor keeps accumulating the data in the application heap until the application eventually crashes with EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW.
The expected (or rather, desired) behavior would be to lose/drop traces to avoid having the telemetry impacting the system stability. I have tried to go over the Otel as well as Micrometer documentation, played with the retry policies
  @Bean
  public MetricExporter grpcMetricExporter() {
    return OtlpGrpcMetricExporter.builder().setEndpoint(tracingEndpoint).setRetryPolicy(
            RetryPolicy.builder().setMaxAttempts(1).build()).build();
  }

and BatchSpanProcessor batch sizes, however neither of thsoe helped to prevent the heap from overflowing.
Did anyone else meet this issue and managed to have more luck in dealing with it?

As far as I understand this issue has nothing to do with Micrometer but it is the OTel SDK that crashes your app in exchange to keeping traces in memory? If so, I would open an issue in OTel's opentelemetry-java repo.

@JonatanIvanov that's what i am planning to do. My attention was focused elsewhere these days and I want to spend some time understanding the OT codebase before creating an issue.
